# Realm Functions on Developer Edition

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I was able to use Realm functions on realm browser, when i was in developer edition. Documentation says i can only have 3 active functions at a time in this edition.

But now i can't seem to find my functions, or options for this in realm studio. Is it not available anymore on developer edition?

Answer (score 1):

Realm developer edition is dead.

Realm studio does not support cloud functions. Pay $$$$ to Realm to continue using realm.